# Join two tables in EntityFramework

Tags: mysql, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have two tables:

- Companies
- Contacts with a one-to-many relations (many contacts in one Company)

Contacts table **EDITED**:

```
public class Contact
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }

    public DateTime updated { get; set; }

    public Boolean hidden { get; set; }

    //Personal Data

    public string title { get; set; }

    public string jobTitle { get; set; }

    public string firstName { get; set; }

    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public string department { get; set; }

    public string email { get; set; }

    public string logoUrl { get; set; }

    public string personalRemarks { get; set; }

    //Telephone list

    public ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    //Addresses

    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    //Bank Data

    public ICollection<Bankdata> Bankdatas { get; set; }

    //Tags

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

}

Companies table **EDITED**:

```
public class Organization
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }

    public DateTime dateUpdated { get; set; }

    public Boolean hidden { get; set; }

    //Company Data

    public string organizationName { get; set; }

    public string taxId { get; set; }

    public string trades { get; set; }

    public string organizationType { get; set; }

    public string actionRadius { get; set; }

    public string organizationRemarks { get; set; }

    public string web { get; set; }

    //Contacts

    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    //Tags

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

}
```

}

I have a method im my repository to select all the contacts in one company

```
    public Organization GetOrganizationById(Guid Id)
    {
        return _context.Organizations
            .Include(c => c.Contacts)
            .Where(c => c.Id == Id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

But since all I have is the company id I need to make a join between the two tables in order to get the name.  Something like:

```
SELECT contacts,*, Organization.name
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN Organization ON Organization.id = Contacts.organization_id
WHERE Organization.id = id;
```

I have tried the following without success:

```
    public Organization GetOrganizationById(Guid Id)
    {
        return _context.Organizations
            .Include(o => o.organizationName)
            .Include(c => c.Contacts)
            .Where(c => c.Id == Id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Any help will be welcome

Comment: Are you using *Entity Framework Code-first*?

Comment: Yes, I am following the Code-First Approach. I created the classes and then used EntityFramework to generate my Database. My contact table has indeed an "organizationId" column. However that code I pasted here does not bring back that column. And and that point I do not know how to add a "select" statement that bring the name of the company

Comment: but your models does not reflect your query. According to your query, you should have `OrganizationId` property on `Contact` model. Additionally, in order to be able to use `Include` you should have [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) like `public virual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }`

Comment: Sorry  I did not published it complete in order to save space here. I will update it now However, the Organizationid column is just in the database, not in my models

Comment: `Include` method is used to load related data. *Related data* means *navigation properties*. You cannot use it with ordinary properties such as `organizationName`. First form of `GetOrganizationById` method in your question should just work fine. When you load data using `FirstOrDefault` it loads all the properties including `organizationName`

Comment: I will have to give a closer look into it, because the GetOrganizationById does not bring anything else than the data from the contacts, without organitationName. Even if the Database has a column: contacts.organizationId

Comment: @RafaelMunoz in your Company class, do you have an OrganizationId property?

Comment: @user449689. In my company class I have an Id ( public Guid Id { get; set; })

Comment: @RafaelMunoz I realized I made a mistake, I wanted to ask you if in your Contact class you have an OrganizationId property to link the contact to the organization

Comment: @user449689. Yes I have an Id in both of my classes. because I have a public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } roroperty in my company class, after running the Entity Framework, I have a column in the contacts table with the name OrganizationsId

Comment: @RafaelMunoz Based on your description, I have given you an answer, please check it out

Answer (score 1):

The right approach is to create a navigation property between the `Organization` class and the `Contact` class. The following code will let you understand the steps you need to do:

```
public class Contact
{
    ...

    // Foreign key for Organization
    public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }

    // Related Organization entity
    [ForeignKey("OrganizationId ")]
    public Organization Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Organization
{
    ...

    // List of related Contacts
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

}
```

After creating a migration with this code you will implement your method as follows:

```
public Organization GetOrganizationById(Guid Id)
{
    return _context.Organizations
        .Include(c => c.Contacts)
        .Where(c => c.Id == Id)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestions but my migrating I have got an error like this:

The index 'IX_Contacts_OrganizationId is dependent on column 'OrganizationId' ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN OrganizationId failed because one or more objects access this column

Comment: I have managed to get the migration done and now I have the data from the organization inside an array. The new problem now is how to aces to that data to sow in the front end. But I will manage it. Thanks
I accept your answer, thanks

Comment: I just noticed that now, I get the companies properties, but I just get 1 single contact, instead all the contacts belonging to the organization. Any idea why?

Comment: @RafaelMunoz are you calling a FirstOrDefault somewhere?

Comment: I did it, but since I had less than 20 points of reputations it takes longer to show up

Comment: @RafaelMunoz ok, sorry about that. Have you worked out the problem about the list? Are you calling a FirstOrDefault somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I did exactly what you told me, but as I said now when I call the contacts of an organization I get Just ONE contact instead the 3 that it has.Which is an incorrect answer. In the other hand, it takes now more than 2 minutes to load a page

Comment: This foreignkey relation is incorrect built, it give me access to the organization data, but just give back ONE contact per organization whcih is also incorrect. In the other hand it slow down the complete solution (until 2 minutes to change a page). Therfore I deactivate it and do not show the name of the organization